# Xamarin PCL App update Android Studio App with losing SharedPreferences

Tags: android, xamarin, sharedpreferences

i have some strange problem. Years ago i publishes an android app, developed in android studio. It workes great an so the times runs. Month ago i developed the same app just in xamarin to publishes it to ios store and more.

But when i send the app to the play store, it wipe all data. I mean really all. I can create an backup file or something in the folder. How can i rescue all data from the sqlite db and SharedPreferences. It caused over 100k app installs. There must be an solutions.

Comment: I was not able to understand if your existing app is Xamarin Android or A Xamarin Forms Android app can you please clarify?

Comment: My existing app in the play store was developed in android studio. if i now publishes my new app (same name and key and developed in xamarin forms) it wipe all data from the old one

Comment: Right so you want to maintain the SQLITE and Shared Preference data?

Comment: Yeah thats right

Comment: No idea anyone?